# Is this paragraph informal conversation or in writing and formal format?

Tags: formal-language, informal-language

I just started learning English and I listen to podcasts like this. My question is that the following paragraph is an informal conversation or in writing and formal format:

> In 1436 in Germany, Johannes Gutenberg, invented the printing press,
> a machine capable of making many copies of the same page of text. Ever
> since, printing has been used around the world to produce books,
> newspapers and magazines.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion.  "conversation" is two or more people talking.  Writing is symbols on a page or a screen.  This is symbols on a screen, so it is writing.  It's not particularly formal, it might be a script or a transcript of something.  What do you mean by "informal conversation"?

Comment: You're right, It's part of a transcript. But I mean if somebody ask me a question about "printing press", could I tell him with these sentences or they seem more formal and in written format as point of view of a native English person? @JamesK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal English.  It is perfectly suitable for a written or a spoken presentation. The comma after "Gutenberg" should be removed.

It is neither notably formal, nor notably informal.

It is not a conversation, since there is only one voice here.